# Adding a new primary key to existing table

Tags: sql-server, primary-key-design

I have table with following details

Table name `EMPLOYEE` and columns

```
EMPID (PK smallint not null)
EMPNAME (varchar 256 not null)
ORG (FK smallint not null)
FUNCTION (FK smallint not null)
EFF_DATE (datetime null)
AUDIT_ID (varchar null)
```

Now I have to add an extra coulmn to this table `ADD_UID` and make it also primary key

I am using this query but failing.

```
ALTER TABLE CVADMIN.EMPLOYEE
 ADD ADD_UID  varchar(32) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY [NON]CLUSTERED (ADD_UID)
go
```

Table '`EMPLOYEE`' already has a primary key defined on it.

**EDIT**

The idea here is the new column should be unique so that if it fails I can throw _KEY_VIOLATION so that some code manipulation is done

Comment: I think you might have to drop the original primary key first, and then create the new one as required. Just remember you can only have ONE primary key per table, thought yuo can have additional unique keys.

Comment: Dropping first key is not good idea as of now because its referenced elsewhere too(2places). How to make sure this additional colum ADD_ID takes unique values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a unique constraint (which is additional to the primary key) do this:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT uc_UID UNIQUE (ADD_UID)
```

Comment: Thanks this works !!! I have a question here.If I want to design the DB for future such that if I add another unique constraint over a new column .How do I distinguish which is seeking unique from JDBC perspective

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but in the example above uc_UID is the name of the constraint and given that it will appear in any exception thrown, you could use that to derive the field that is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

We can add new columns on any tables by alter statement but added column can be `null` and you know primary key does not accept `null` on any column.
Therefore we can not create primary key on the newly added column by alter statement.

Comment: No. This is not the problem. You can prevent null value by setting default value with not null by executing `ALTER TABLE x ADD y INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;` and the column can be also unique on a table with one row. But definitely the primary index can be only ONE.